# Python multiprocessing: add tasks to queue but prevent them being picked for a given time

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, delay

I am using multiprocessing with multiple workers (subclasses of `multiprocessing.Process`) and queues (`multiprocessing.JoinableQueue`), to implement a complex workflow of data manipulation.

One of the workers (`JobSender`) is submitting jobs to a remote system (*a web service*), which returns an identifier immediately. Those jobs can take a very long time to be performed.
I therefore have another worker (`StatusPoller`) in charge of polling that remote system for status of the job. To do so, the `JobSender` adds the identifier in a queue that the `StatusPoller` uses as input. If the job is not completed, the `StatusPoller` puts the identifier back on the same queue. If the job is completed, the `StatusPoller` retrieves the result information and then adds it to a list (`multiprocessing.Manager.list()`).

My question: I don't want to hammer the remote system with continuous requests for status, which would happen in my setup. I want to introduce a delay somewhere to ensure that status polling for any given identifier only happens every 20 seconds.

Currently I'm doing this by having a `time.sleep(20)` just before the `StatusPoller` puts the identifier back on the queue. But that means that the `StatusPoller` is now idle for 20 seconds and cannot pick up another polling task from the queue. I will have multiple `StatusPollers` but I can't have one for each of the jobs (there might be hundreds of those).

```
class StatusPoller(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, polling_queue, results_queue, errors_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.polling_queue = polling_queue
        self.results_queue = results_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # Pick a task from the queue
            next_id = self.polling_queue.get()

            # Poison pill => shutdown
            if next_id == 'END':
                self.polling_queue.task_done()
                break

            # Process the task
            response = remote_system.get_status(next_id)

            if response == "IN_PROGRESS":
                time.sleep(20)
                self.polling_queue.put(next_id)
            else:
                self.results_queue.put(response)

            self.polling_queue.task_done()
```

Any idea how to implement such a workflow?

Comment: You can use an intermediate queue and an intermediate thread

Comment: I thought of that, but how would that change anything?  Now it's the other thread that would get blocked with delays, woudln't it?

Answer (score 0):

When you consider that the `multiprocessing.Process` and `multithreading.Threading` classes can be instantiated with the *target* keyword, I consider it to be an antipattern to actually subclass these classes since you then lose some flexibility and reuse. In fact, in your case I would think that given that `StatusPoller` is just waiting on a queue and a reply from a network, that multithreading would be more than adequate, especially if, as you say, you have "hundreds of those." I also cannot see in your current code the need for a joinable queue.

So I would suggest using multithreading with regular `queue.Queue` instances and the [`sched.scheduler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html?highlight=schedule#sched.scheduler) class instance from the `sched` module, which can be shared among all `StatusPoller` instances as the code appears to the thread safe. Here is the general idea:

```py
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import time

# Start of modified sched.scheduler code:
#########################################################
# Heavily modified from sched.scheduler

import time
import heapq
from collections import namedtuple
import threading
from time import monotonic as _time


class Event(namedtuple('Event', 'time, priority, action, argument, kwargs')):
    __slots__ = []
    def __eq__(s, o): return (s.time, s.priority) == (o.time, o.priority)
    def __lt__(s, o): return (s.time, s.priority) <  (o.time, o.priority)
    def __le__(s, o): return (s.time, s.priority) <= (o.time, o.priority)
    def __gt__(s, o): return (s.time, s.priority) >  (o.time, o.priority)

_sentinel = object()

class Scheduler():
    """
    Code modified from sched.scheduler
    """

    delayfunc = time.sleep

    def __init__(self, timefunc=_time):
        """Initialize a new instance, passing the time functions"""
        self._queue = []
        self.timefunc = timefunc
        self.got_event = threading.Condition(threading.RLock())
        self.thread_started = False

    def enterabs(self, time, priority, action, argument=(), kwargs=_sentinel):
        """Enter a new event in the queue at an absolute time.

        Returns an ID for the event which can be used to remove it,
        if necessary.

        """
        if kwargs is _sentinel:
            kwargs = {}
        event = Event(time, priority, action, argument, kwargs)
        with self.got_event:
            if not self.thread_started:
                self.thread_started = True
                threading.Thread(target=self.run, daemon=True).start()
            heapq.heappush(self._queue, event)
            # Show new Event has been entered:
            self.got_event.notify()
        return event # The ID

    def cancel(self, event):
        """Remove an event from the queue.

        This must be presented the ID as returned by enter().
        If the event is not in the queue, this raises ValueError.

        """
        with self.got_event:
            self._queue.remove(event)
            heapq.heapify(self._queue)

    def enter(self, delay, priority, action, argument=(), kwargs=_sentinel):
        """A variant that specifies the time as a relative time.

        This is actually the more commonly used interface.

        """
        time = self.timefunc() + delay
        return self.enterabs(time, priority, action, argument, kwargs)

    def empty(self):
        """Check whether the queue is empty."""
        with self.got_event:
            return not self._queue

    def run(self):
        """Execute events until the queue is empty."""

        # localize variable access to minimize overhead
        # and to improve thread safety
        got_event = self.got_event
        q = self._queue
        timefunc = self.timefunc
        delayfunc = self.delayfunc
        pop = heapq.heappop
        while True:
            try:
                while True:
                    with got_event:
                        got_event.wait_for(lambda: len(q) != 0)
                        time, priority, action, argument, kwargs = q[0]
                        now = timefunc()
                        if time > now:
                            # Wait for either the time to elapse or a new
                            # event to be added:
                            got_event.wait(timeout=(time - now))
                            continue
                        pop(q)
                    action(*argument, **kwargs)
                    delayfunc(0)   # Let other threads run
            except:
                pass

    @property
    def queue(self):
        """An ordered list of upcoming events.

        Events are named tuples with fields for:
            time, priority, action, arguments, kwargs

        """
        # Use heapq to sort the queue rather than using 'sorted(self._queue)'.
        # With heapq, two events scheduled at the same time will show in
        # the actual order they would be retrieved.
        with self.got_event:
            events = self._queue[:]
        return list(map(heapq.heappop, [events]*len(events)))
###########################################################

def re_queue(polling_queue, id):
    polling_queue.put(id)
    

class StatusPoller:
    scheduler = Scheduler()
    
    def __init__(self, polling_queue, results_queue, errors_queue):
        self.polling_queue = polling_queue
        self.results_queue = results_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # Pick a task from the queue
            next_id = self.polling_queue.get()

            # Poison pill => shutdown
            if next_id == 'END':
                break

            # Process the task
            response = remote_system.get_status(next_id)

            if response == "IN_PROGRESS":
                self.scheduler.enter(20, 1, re_queue, argument=(self.polling_queue, next_id))
            else:
                self.results_queue.put(response)
```

**Explanation**

First, why did I say that I saw no reason for a `JoinableQueue`? The `run` method is programmed to return if it finds an input message that is 'END'. But because of the way this method when finding "IN_PROGRES" responses from the remote system requeues messages back onto the `pollinq_queue`, the possibility exists that when `END` is received and `run` terminates that there is one or more of these requeued  messages remaining on the queue. So how can another process or thread depend on calling `polling_queue.join()` without possibly hanging? It cannot.

Instead, if you have N processes or threads (we haven't decided yet which) doing `get` requests against a single queue instance, it should suffice to just put N 'END' shutdown messages on the queue. This will result in the N processes terminating. The main process now instead of joining the queue just joins the N processes or threads *if it wishes to block on the actual termination of these processes/threads*.

The way I would use a `JoinableQueue`, which I don't think fits your use case, would be if the processes/threads were in an infinite loop never terminating, that is, not quitting "prematurely" and therefore never leaving items left on the queue. You would make these processes/threads *daemon* processes so that they would eventually end when the main process eventually terminates. So you could not force a termination with an 'END' message. So I just don't see how a `JoinableQueue` works here, but you can point out to me if I have misunderstood something.

**Yes, `StatusPoller` could be the target of a `Process` instance (or even a subclass of `Process`** as you originally had it, although except for the fact that is how you currently have it coded, I see no advantage to doing that). But it seems to me that it will be spending most of its time waiting on either getting from a queue or getting a network response. In both cases it will release the Global Interpreter Lock and multithreading should be very performant. Threads will also take up far fewer resources if we are indeed talking about creating hundreds of instances of these tasks, especially if you are running under Windows. You will also not be able to share the `scheduler`, which runs in its own thread, across all `StatusPoller` instances. There will be one scheduler now running in each process since each `StatusPoller` is running in its own process.

Comment: The shared code is massively simplified from my actual code, just to illustrate the situation. I have multiple other workers and queues, which is why I’m using multiprocessing, Process and JoinableQueue instead of multi threading. Is there any reason why the scheduler would not work in those cases?

Comment: The answer has been updated with an explanation.

Comment: Actually my answer doesn't work because the `sched` module doesn't work the way I thought, i.e. the thread terminates as soon as its event queue is empty. I might have something else for you.

Comment: Yes, my oversimplified code, without context, could indeed lead to the behaviour you're describing. The main part of the code (not shared) joins the `result_queue` and when it's got them all (it knows in advance how many there will be), it sends an "END" to all the StatusPollers, before doing some further post-processing of the results. This seems to work as expected.  I am however trying to understand the 2nd paragraph of your *Explanation * however, to make sure I understand it.  I get your point about multithreading being more suitable, but it would be a fairly major change at this point...

Comment: Then don't do make the change. I had to modify the Python built-in `schedule` code because once it finds there are no more future events to be scheduled, the thread terminates and that's no good. It was meant to be used where you just set all the events you want *in advance* specifying the start time and the you call the `run` method. It did not even run in a separate thread. So I had to modify it to run as a separate thread and when it finds the event list is empty, it simply waits until a new entry is added.

Comment: As far as the second paragraph of the explanation. When `run` see `END` it terminates without getting any more items from the queue. If you have N processes reading from the queue and there are N of these 'END' items on the queue, each process is guaranteed to process one and only one of these `END` messages because as soon as it sees the first one it terminates. So all N processes will terminate. I can't explain it any better than that.